# Filter dataframe by 10

Tags: r

```
df=data.frame(col1=c(100, 100 ,100, 120 ,100 ,100, 100 ,110 ,100, 100, 100, 110, 110 ,100 ,160, 110  90, 170 ,120, 160, 110),
col2=c(13.4739 ,13.5536, 10.7045, 30.6985 ,10.9025, 13.5834, 15.6149, 23.5638 ,12.0090 ,12.1103 ,12.5012, 23.9931, 23.9931, 13.5775 ,56.9106, 24.1769  ,8.3623 ,65.6385, 30.0437, 58.8961, 25.2614))

df[df$col2>60&df$col2<70,c("col1","col2")]
df[df$col2>50&df$col2<60,c("col1","col2")]
df[df$col2>40&df$col2<50,c("col1","col2")]
df[df$col2>30&df$col2<40,c("col1","col2")]
df[df$col2>20&df$col2<30,c("col1","col2")]
df[df$col2>10&df$col2<20,c("col1","col2")]
df[df$col2>0&df$col2<10,c("col1","col2")]
```

I want to filter a dataframe that way, but is there a function that does this avoiding all this code?

I thought of creating a sequence from 0 to max(df$col2) by=10 and loop,

```
seq(0,max(df$col2),by=10)
```

but the result will not come out like the one above because the bottom filter repeats on top:

````r
# observe 10
df [df $ col2> 10 & df $ col2 <20, c ("col1", "col2")]
df [df $ col2> 0 & df $ col2 <10, c ("col1", "col2")]```
````

My intention is to create a df, with the two columns respecting the filter condition

Expected output:

```
filter1=df24[df24$col2>50&df24$col2<60,c("col1","col2")]
>filter1
   col1    col2
15  160 56.9106
20  160 58.8961

> filter2=df24[df24$col2>60&df24$col2<70,c("col1","col2")]
> filter2
   col1    col2
18  170 65.6385

> class(filter1)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: what do you intend to achieve with filters?
please post your sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the `split` function:

```
split(df, findInterval(df$col2, seq(0, max(df$col2), 10)))

$`1`
   col1   col2
17   90 8.3623

$`2`
   col1    col2
1   100 13.4739
2   100 13.5536
3   100 10.7045
5   100 10.9025
6   100 13.5834
7   100 15.6149
9   100 12.0090
10  100 12.1103
11  100 12.5012
14  100 13.5775

......
```

if you do need to also note the ranges that do not contain any data, then use `cut` instead. ie:

```
 split(df, cut(df$col2, seq(0, max(df$col2) + 10, 10)))
....
$`(30,40]`
   col1    col2
4   120 30.6985
19  120 30.0437

$`(40,50]`
[1] col1 col2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`(50,60]`
   col1    col2
15  160 56.9106
20  160 58.8961
....
```

Comment: @KmnsE2 it works regardless of the number of columns. What exactly do you mean that you want to select one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cut_interval`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/cut_interval.html) and [`group_split`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_split(grp = cut_interval(col2, length = 10, labels = FALSE))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
   col1  col2 cut_grp
  <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1   170  8.36       1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 3
    col1  col2 cut_grp
   <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
 1   100  13.5       2
 2   100  13.6       2
 3   100  10.7       2
 4   100  10.9       2
 5   100  13.6       2
 6   100  15.6       2
 7   100  12.0       2
 8   100  12.1       2
 9   100  12.5       2
10   100  13.6       2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
   col1  col2 cut_grp
  <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1   110  23.6       3
2   110  24.0       3
3   110  24.0       3
4 11090  24.2       3

[[4]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   col1  col2 cut_grp
  <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1   120  30.7       4
2   160  30.0       4

[[5]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   col1  col2 cut_grp
  <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1   160  56.9       6
2   110  58.9       6

[[6]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
   col1  col2 cut_grp
  <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1   120  65.6       7
```

Comment: you have `170, 8.36` in group 1. Should that not be a dataframe by itself?

Comment: yes, good catch, thanks.  fixed now - it's the difference between using the `n` vs `length` argument in `cut_interval()`.  much appreciated!

Comment: `group_split(df, grp = cut_interval(col2, length = 10))` is the best way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach:

```
#Create index
index <- seq(0,max(df$col2),by=10)
#Loop
for(i in index)
{
  df[df$col2> i & df$col2 <i+10, c ("col1", "col2")]
}
```

And if you want to create individual elements you can use a list like this:

```
#Create index
index <- seq(0,max(df$col2),by=10)
index <- rev(index)
#Create list
List <- list()
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(index))
{
  List[[i]] <- df[df$col2> index[i] & df$col2 <index[i]+10, c ("col1", "col2")]
}
```

Output:

```
List
[[1]]
   col1    col2
18  170 65.6385

[[2]]
   col1    col2
15  160 56.9106
20  160 58.8961

[[3]]
[1] col1 col2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[4]]
   col1    col2
4   120 30.6985
19  120 30.0437

[[5]]
   col1    col2
8   110 23.5638
12  110 23.9931
13  110 23.9931
16  110 24.1769
21  110 25.2614

[[6]]
   col1    col2
1   100 13.4739
2   100 13.5536
3   100 10.7045
5   100 10.9025
6   100 13.5834
7   100 15.6149
9   100 12.0090
10  100 12.1103
11  100 12.5012
14  100 13.5775

[[7]]
   col1   col2
17   90 8.3623
```

The last loop replicates the same logic of your individual filters at the start of your question.